# Regarding `sprintf` and `nm`

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, strcpy, nm

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c[10] = "hello!";
    char d[10] = {'\0'};

    sprintf (d, "%s", c);
    return printf("%s\n", d);
}
```

After compiling with `gcc -Wall -pedantic a.c` (GCC 4.8.5 on CentOS), when I run `nm` on the executable, I can see that `strcpy` is listed as an undefined symbol:

```
 nm a.out | grep strcpy
                 U strcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

How and why does `strcpy` come in the picture here? If I compile the same program on GCC 8.3.0, the `strcpy` symbol is nowhere to be found in the output of `nm`. Also, on GCC 4.8.5, if I add a space before the `%` sign, `sprintf (d, " %s", c)`, the `sprintf` call is *not* replaced with `strcpy`.

The assembly code generated by using the `-S` switch with `gcc` supports these findings. Could somebody please help me understand what is going on here?

The customer audits the executable and will raise a red flag if they find a call to `strcpy`. I just want to understand why the `sprintf` call is replaced with `strcpy`.

Comment: Maybe the compiler optimizes the call to `sprintf()` into `strcpy(d, c)` — which achieves the same result.  Look at the assembler — use the `-S` option to GCC; the output file from `source.c` should be `source.s`.

Comment: Prefer [snprintf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to `sprintf` to avoid buffer overflow. Compile with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) -so GCC 10 in january 2021- as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -fverbose-asm -O2 -S a.c` and look inside the generated `a.s` assembler file

Comment: Also, explain why you need to avoid `strcpy`. In most implementations, it is a very optimized routine.

Comment: It's more likely that downgrading the compiler would work than that upgrading it would.  Older versions probably don't make that sort of optimization.  Newer versions almost certainly do.  Also consider whether suppressing optimization `-O0` helps — it might, it might not.

Comment: Use `memcpy`, or write a loop, or `sprintf(d, "%.*s", (int)sizeof(d) - 1, c);`, or...

Comment: Motivation lacking. Why is the `strcpy` a problem? Is it ok if `sprintf` is not called **at all**? Otherwise, this is exactly because of the as-if rule and that the compiler is allowed to assume that the builtin functions have the same behaviour as library functions. Which specifically might not be true in case of `snprintf` **because** it does produce `(null)` with glibc instead of crashing like strcpy would **most likely** do, but that's undefined behaviour for you.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala @BasileStarynkevitch The customer runs some audits on the executable\ provided. They say `strcpy` is a potential security threat and have requested that it be removed.

Comment: @babon so, it is **valid then**. **The use of `sprintf` is a security threat. The compiler replaced with it another functionally equivalent security threat.**

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The `strcpy` calls were replaced with an in-house string copy routine. Then I came across the fact that `sprintf` calls were replaced with `strcpy`. So, we will have to do away with the `sprintf`s as well.

Comment: @babon **of course** you have to. It is a security audit. Otherwise this is just the programming equivalent of the old joke [`Problem:  "Evidence of hydraulic leak on right main landing gear." Solution: "Evidence removed."`](https://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/97/Jun/usaf.html)

Comment: More important question is whether the `strcpy` calls are replaced with a **secure solution** or if you just wiped the hydraulic fluid?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's a fascinating read :). I did not just 'remove the evidence'. `strcpy` was replaced with a secure solution with bounds checking and memory overlap checking now in place and the assignment operator is used to copy the string character by character. I can't share the source due to legal restrictions. I was just looking for a way to *not* make `sprintf` look like `strcpy` to the customer. Of course, the customer has no problem with `sprintf`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not get *why* the customer wouldn't have a problem with `sprintf` if they have a problem with `strcpy` *provided* that they both can suffer from the same failure. Are you saying that *all usages* of sprintf are specifically audited already to ensure that the content fits in the target buffer? You should really consider [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 1):

> My requirement is that `strcpy` should not show up in the list of symbols returned by `nm`.

## Why?

But with [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) on Linux/x86-64 you could have your own `static inline` variant of `strcpy`, perhaps using some [extended `asm`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) instruction (perhaps some [REP STOS](https://www.fermimn.edu.it/linux/quarta/x86/rep.htm)...)

And you could also improve GCC with your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

You could also link your executable statically, and compile and link it with `gcc -O2 -flto -Wall`, then use [strip(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html).

> How does strcpy come in the picture here?

Compile your `a.c` [using](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) `gcc -fverbose-asm -Wall -Wextra -O3 -fdump-tree-all -S a.c` and you will understand what the compiler has done, by looking into the many `a.c.*` dump files and into the `a.s` file.

The compiler is allowed to optimize `printf` (there is a `__builtin_printf`....). Check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or some newer C standard.

Notice that binary analysis tools like [BINSEC](https://binsec.github.io/) will "find" code equivalent to `strcpy`

#### so your requirement is not reasonable and you should explain it

If you need some [code obfuscation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129296/the-case-for-code-obfuscation) (which I believe is wrong most of the time), you'll better use more sophisticated techniques.... e.g. machine code generation at runtime using [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) or [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/).

Another possible approach (illustrated by my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program) would be to generate some obfuscated C code at runtime, compile it as a plugin, and load that generated plugin with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).

To increase the security, or safety, or reliability of your C source code, use [code reviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review), follow guidelines like [MISRA C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C), consider *also* using static analysis frameworks like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (or perhaps, in spring 2021, [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) described in [this](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) DRAFT report). In *many cases*, using `snprintf` or `strcpy` is safe (and in *some cases*, could be "proven" to be so; be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)). To increase the confidence put in the generated executable, consider using [CompCert](https://compcert.inria.fr/) as your C compiler.

PS. If you need to protect your code (either C source code or the generated [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)), you should ask your lawyer help in writing legal contracts protecting it.

Comment: First of all, I did not downvote earlier. Thanks for answering my question. The problem I have is that the customer runs some audits on the executables provided and as soon as they find a `strcpy`, they raise a red flag. The `strcpy` calls were replaced with an in-house safer alternative and now I find that I will have to replace the `sprintf` calls as well. I just wanted to understand why `sprintf` translates to `strcpy` on GCC 4.8. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I believe you should start a discussion with your customer, instead of changing your source code. Notice also that the source code of `sprintf` is inside [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), and the source code of the optimization passes working on it is inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). **Both are free software, and you are allowed to study their source code and improve it**